# How to read image from specific path in SQL Server 2005 stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005, image, stored-procedures

I need to read the image from the specific path. I pass only path as parameter and that image will return by the procedures in image or byte format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take appropriate SQL injection precautions.

```
EXEC('SELECT image_data
FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK N''' + @Path + ''',
SINGLE_BLOB)
AS ImageSource(image_data);')
```

Comment: it is not working give me error like this -- Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\1.jpg" does not exist.

Comment: The file needs to exist **on the server** (or network share visible to the server) and in a place that the SQL Server account has permissions to read.